# Creating an instance without endless instantiation

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor

The line: `mdv = new MapDesignerView();`creates an endless instantiation (infinite loop). See in code below:

```
public partial class MapDesignerView : Form
{
    public  MapDesignerView mdv;
    public  Map map;
    public  MapController mapController;
    public MapConstructor mapConstructor;
    MouseEventHandler detectMouse;

    public MapDesignerView()
    {
        mdv = new MapDesignerView();
        map = new Map(mdv);
        mapController = new MapController(map);
        mapConstructor = new MapConstructor(mapController);
        detectMouse = new MouseEventHandler(mapController);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

As you can see I need to make an instance of the `MapDesignerView` class inside the `mapDesignView` class, to pass to another class constructor. How do I pass this form to the Map constructor in a different way so it is not endlessly instantiating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `this`, which refers to the current instance.

Comment: Yep thanks. Will accept this answer in ten minutes when it allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to pass an instance of `MapDesignerView` to itself, you can do so by using a constructor with a contract like:

```
public MapDesignerView(MapDesignerView map)
```

Comment: How would you instantiate that?

Comment: Every closed class in .NET (even forms) can be instantiated using `new` (or a factory method of some sort). I didn't set the requirements, just offering a potential solution.

Comment: How can you pass an instance to itself? Thats why we have this.

Comment: Pass `null` to the initial instance to indicate top level, _or_ rather than replacing the existing constructor, override it with the overload proposed. The implementation is up to the asker based on their requirements... not the person trying to answer one small part of the overall project.

Answer (score 1):

```
mdv = new MapDesignerView();
map = new Map(mdv);
```

This creates a new object (eventually causing the stack to overflow)

Instead what you want is

```
map = new Map(this);
```

And by extension you no longer need the `mdv` variable.